# Couldn't find a documentation for a filter API in plugin development

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm new to wordpress plugin development, I read the whole documentation this afternoon http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference, I tried to write some code, like this in plugin file:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'my_own_function', 10, 2);
```

**Function is:**

```
function my_own_function($title, $post_id){
    return $title. $post_id;
}
```

This plugin really worked, but the documentation doesn't tell the filter API `the_title` has two arguments, and what those arguments are. That's the problem! If it doesn't tell, how would I know?

**Here I just quote the official documentation relevant excerpt:**

```
the_title 
applied to the post title retrieved from the database, prior to printing on the screen (also used in some other operations, such as trackbacks).
```

So, my **question is:** How can I find a full explanation of filter API such as `the_title`? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one answer: **You always go and read the source code**.

There are some online tools that help you with this, specifically [Adam Brown's Hooks List](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook), which contains links to the source code where you can read what arguments filters and actions take.

Be aware that a single filter can have variable amounts of arguments depending on where it is being used. For example, in [class-wp-posts-list-table.php](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/the_title?version=3.3&file=wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php) `the_title` filter sends out one argument only, instead of two like in [post-template.php](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/the_title?version=3.2&file=wp-includes/post-template.php)

So, again, always read the source specifically on where the filter is being applied.

Answer (score 0):

### How-to add the filter

As a rule of thumb:

> If the filter has more than one var, then you have to add **priority & num_args** to the filter

```
# Example:
// RIGHT
add_filter( 'the_title', 'your_callback_fn', 20, 2 );
// WRONG
add_filter( 'the_title', 'your_callback_fn' );
```

### How-to to return in the callback

Another rule of thumb (might not be always true, but I haven't found the opposite so far):

> Always return the first argument

```
// Example
function your_callback_fn( $var_A, $var_B, $var_C )
{
    // do stuff - the other vars (B-C) are here for your help

    // ! important: return the 1st var
    return $var_A;
}
add_action( 'the_funk', 'your_callback_fn', 10, 3 );
```